# Gradient Not working in iOS 9

Tags: ios, uiview, cagradientlayer

I am doing something like this to add a gradient view to my view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    dm=[Datamanager sharedManager];

    vwGradient=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, dm.screenWidth, 100)];
    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer=[CAGradientLayer layer];
   gradientLayer.frame=vwGradient.bounds;
   gradientLayer.colors=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor  colorWithRed:61.0f green:81.0f blue:119.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor,(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:9.0f green:9.0f blue:38.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor,nil];
   gradientLayer.locations=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], nil];
   [vwGradient.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
   [self.view addSubview:vwGradient];

}
```

But nothing appears on my view. Why is that? How can I do this?
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[UIColor colorWithRed:...]` uses RGB values between 0 and 1, they way you use it it's all white.

Try `[UIColor colorWithRed:61.0/255.0 green:81.0/255.0 blue: 91.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. Totally forgot